# Open a dropdown with right click in Vue3 and Vuetify3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to work on the context menu for Vue3. I want to show the list of items under the `v-menu` by right-clicking on a dropdown button. I am working on [this link](https://codepen.io/majesticpotatoe-the-bashful/pen/MWWWWjR) as a reference but when I tried to do the same in my Vue3 file, It gives me an error like this-

[image]

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Here is the code-

```
<v-menu offset-y>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      dark
      v-bind="props"
      @contextmenu.prevent="props.click"
      >
      Dropdown
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(item, index) in menuClick"
      :key="index"
      @click=""
      >
      <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't discover any `context menu` event in Vue3's doc and Vuetify's menu API. Although, I have an alternative in my mind that can do this job. **You can utilize the `.right` modifier sync with `v-model` to open the menu with the right click of a button.**

Here is the strategy-

1. Use `v-model` to control the `v-menu` toggling status.
2. On the right-click, set the `v-model` to true so the menu will be open.
3. On the left-click (default) set the `v-model` to false. (Do this step only if you don't want to open the menu on the default click.)

Here is a functioning demo-

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  data: () => ({
    menu: false,
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
    ],
  }),
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div class="d-flex justify-space-around mb-5 font-weight-bold">
      I will open only with the right-click.
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-space-around">
      <v-menu v-model="menu">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            v-bind="props"
            @click.left.prevent="menu = false"
            @click.right.prevent="menu = true"
            >
            Dropdown
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            :value="index"
            >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked beautifully. Hope that contextmenu would soon be implemented in vue3 though